# Probability of 2 darts being same distance away from center of a dartboard

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, random-variables

Out of curiosity, I have been thinking about the probability of 2 darts uniformly thrown being the same distance away from the center of a dartboard of radius 1 unit, and wanted to check if my reasoning of this problem was correct:

Define $X$ to be the distance of the first dart from the center, and $f(x)$ as the PDF of $X$. Such probability is $\int_0^1 (f(x)\cdot0)dx = 0$ according to my reasoning. I have conceptually justified the integral by thinking of partitioning the dartboard by drawing annuli around the center, and considering the discrete approximation of how far each of the darts are from the center by considering only into which partition they fall- and thinking of each partition has having an area dx, which I consider going to $0$. Then we partition the probability of the second dart equaling the first dart by which values $X$ assumes, so we sum over all possibilities of $X$- and the second dart being equal to this value is independent of this dart, so we multiply this with $f(x)dx$- and the probability of the second dart being this far away from the center is $0$, as there are an uncountable number of distances away from the center which are possible, so a single one has measure 0. And when we take the limit of $dx$ as it goes to $0$, we get the sum turn into this integral.

Is the above reasoning correct? Even if so, does anyone have a better way to explain the probability of this event?

Comment: Real darts have positive radius but you seem to have assumed $0$ - so it is no surprise you find the probability of collision is $0$.  (It seems you have also only looked at distance from the centre; you could have looked at the probability of the middle of the second dart being less than two radii from the middle of the first dart.)

Comment: @Henry I have edited the question; I meant to ask about something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different take: let $X_1, X_2$ denote random variables modeling the distance to the center for the first and second throw respectively.

Assuming the player has constant skill and the throws are independent, the variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid.

The essential additional assumption here is that the distribution of $X_1$ (which is the same as that of $X_2$) is continuous, meaning that it has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure.

By independence, the vector $(X_1,X_2)$ also has a density with respect to $\lambda_2$ and
letting $\Delta = \{(x,x):x\in \mathbb R\}$, we have $$P(X_1=X_2) = P((X_1,X_2)\in \Delta) = 0,$$ where the last equality follows from $\lambda_2(\Delta) = 0$.